# MacBook Early 2015 suddenly doesn't startup anymore

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

[image]MacBook Early 2015 suddenly doesn't startup anymore and hangs on loading screen.
I used Diagnostics using D on startup, no problems.
tried everything i know Nvram reset and SMC reset.
tried booting to savemode, worked only one time and freezes almost immediately.
in verbose mode i got this result...

Please help.

[image: Verbose Mode]

Comment: Can you boot to the Recovery Partition and run Disk Utility to Repair the Disk?

Comment: no unfortunately not, ive tried that! not able to reach Recovery partition, also tried to use a bootable usb stick to boot from, also freezes on loading screen.

Comment: If it won't boot from a USB stick (that is known to work), then that suggests it's not the disk, but some other aspect of the hardware. Take it to an Apple Store, or a decent independent Apple repair shop.

Comment: It would appear that you are successfully booting into `single-user mode`.  Have you tried mounting the disk and running `/sbin/fsck -fy` ??

Comment: i've tried to run /sbin/fsck -fy, but was unable to mount the the disk. dont know how.

Comment: Your screenshot is from Single User Mode. Can you please reboot in Verbose Mode (CMD+V) instead? I would like to see a console log of the failed state. Alternatively, type "exit" at the command prompt.

Comment: i've updated the picture right now, at this point is freezes.

Comment: those `/sbin/mount...` commands will allow you to mount the different partitions.     then the `fsck` command should work.

Comment: Unfortunately im not able to type at that moment the machine freezes.

Comment: Ok, you've got a panic, great! Now we need to see the beginning of the panic report, which will show us its signature. Can you take a high speed (slow-mo) video of that process and grab the last few screenfuls of text to share as photos?

Comment: I've uploaded the video to youtube hopefully you can see something on it https://youtube.com/shorts/H-FJmJtRvWo?feature=share

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/UouHbMMojiI?feature=share

Answer (score 1):

After doing an initial triage with you in comments, we were able to determine that the proximal cause of the hang is a **kernel panic**. I reviewed the video that I asked you to take of the boot process. Because the video is neither high-speed/slow-motion nor high resolution, I was not able to read the panic text clearly. However, from prior experience I can tell what the approximate panic message is from this screencap:

[image: Screencap of boot process, indicating a machine check exception kernel panic]

This is not just a regular kernel panic but in fact is specifically an Intel **Machine Check Exception (MCE)**. It's a low-level fault that was detected by the CPU itself, rather than macOS. This particular exception appears to occur on CPUs `2` and `3` and in both CPUs it's associated with the silicon subsystems belonging to `MCA bank 4`. Bank 4 is an uncore (i.e., global, not core-local) bank whose exact subsystems would be specified by the family-specific reference manual. Unfortunately I'm not able to read the MCA STATUS or ADDR register values, nor even the CPU family ID, so I can't hazard a further guess on what may be the underlying cause.

Even so, the fact that this started occurring suddenly, without you changing anything on either the software side nor the hardware side, and is 100% reproducible, indicates to me that you're looking at a **sudden hardware failure**. On a 7 year old machine, this wouldn't be a shocking discovery.

You're welcome to try getting higher resolution and higher FPS videos and I'll review your logs again to try to determine more precisely from the MCA bank registers where in hardware the error might be originating, but my prediction is that you are looking at something that can't be fixed in software.

Your best bet is to take the machine to an Apple-authorized repair center.

Comment: I've tried to make a better video, trying to get a complete answer. https://youtu.be/-203ICNpm4s

Comment: @Jeffrey_Jeremia this log does not show a panic. Also the resolution and framerate are no better. Regardless, my advice above still applies: You need hardware-level support.